# Localize Languages names in Language Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table that contains all Languages:

```
create table dbo.[Languages]
( 
  Code nvarchar (4) not null
    constraint PK_Languages_Code primary key clustered (Code),
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
    constraint UQ_Languages_Name unique (Name)                   
)
```

I use this table to localize the content of other tables such as:

```
create table dbo.Countries ( 
  Code nvarchar (4) not null
    constraint PK_Countries_Code primary key clustered (Code)
)

create table dbo.CountriesLocalized (
  Code nvarchar (4) not null,
  LanguageCode nvarchar(4) not null,
  Name nvarchar (120) not null
    constraint UQ_Countries_CountryCode_LanguageCode unique (CountryCode, LanguageCode)
)
```

This works fine and I am using this approach in many tables ...

But I also need to localized the Languages Names ... How should I do that?

Comment: why localizing languages Names if Languages table contains only an `ID` and `Language Name`. this table cannot be normalized more than that.

Comment: Because I am building an API and sometimes I need to return all languages and sometimes I need to return the names in English, French or other language

Comment: It's just like any of the other tables: `dbo.LanguagesLocalized` has columns `Code`, `LanguageCode` and `Name`. You can either remove `Name` from `dbo.Languages` or pick a convention, e.g. always use Elbonian, so that you have at least one name for each language. A `union` can pick up the default name from `Languages` if there isn't a localized name in `LanguagesLocalized`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your language table as a hierarchy table by adding a **parent language id** that is a recursive relation with `Code` column

```
create table dbo.[Languages]
( 
  Code nvarchar (4) not null
    constraint PK_Languages_Code primary key clustered (Code),
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
    constraint UQ_Languages_Name unique (Name)      ,
  ParentCode nvarchar(4) null             
)
```

Or add a *Code Kind* column that refer to a *languageKind* table that contains only main languages.